# Seemingly useless typecast in C

Tags: c, casting

I found [this](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/) C tutorial on sockets, and I came across this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *hostname = "www.google.com";
    char ip[100];
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i;

    if ((he = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
        herror("gethostbyname");
        return 1;
    }

    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

    for (i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
    }

    printf("%s resolved to: %s\n", hostname, ip);
    return 0;
}
```

The part that seems useless to me is:

```
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;

    for (i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
    }
```

And would make much more sense to me if it were this:

```
    for (i = 0; he->h_addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strcpy(ip, he->h_addr_list[i]);
    }
```

So I tried this, and it compiled fine, but when I ran this it output this:

```
www.google.com resolved to: J}�
```

But the expected output was this: `www.google.com resolved to: 74.125.225.17`

I have no idea why its necessary to convert `he->h_addr_list` which is the type `(char **)`, to `(struct in_addr **)`, only to convert each address back to `(char **)` right after.

Why is this necessary, it seems very strange to me. Also, why is the output of my version all weird?

Comment: Simple, the ip addresses are stored in 4 bytes not in the human readable form. That's why the first working version is using the inet_ntoa call to convert them to a human readable form.

Comment: Casting `char**` to `struct in_addr**` is wrong.

Comment: You have to define addr_list first.

Comment: @Igor: `addr_list` is defined at the top of `main()`.

Comment: @BillyONeal Add a value to it. My mistake

Comment: @Igor: No, he doesn't.

Comment: @Schoentoon: why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: `h_addr_list` is of type `(char**)` because it can store a list of pointers of different types; so `(char**)` is used as a convenient common denominator; there are no real characters pointed to by them. The actual type of host addresses depends on what's stored in the `he->h_addrtype`.

Comment: @maerics I felt like my explanation was too short and too incomplete for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

The type of `h_addr_list` is `char**`, because it points at arbitrary buffers that happen to contain internet addresses.

The internet addresses are in their raw numeric form -- a normal IPv4 address fits into a 32 bit integer, for example. (x.x.x.x where each x is 0-255 == 8 bits)

To convert the numeric form to a string form you can use, you need to pass the address to `inet_ntoa`. It formats the address for you.

Unfortunately, `h_addr_list`'s type is incompatible with that call, forcing a cast. Were this to be done again `h_addr_list`'s type would probably have been setup in such a way as to not require the cast.

Comment: The reason that it isn't `struct in_addr**` is that different address types use different structures, and `in_addr` is only for IPv4. IPv6 uses `in6_addr`.

Comment: @interjay: There are lots of ways to achieve that without forcing users to do unsafe pointer casts. A union would work. Having `inet_ntoa` have a `char*` version would work too.

Comment: Sure there are other ways. I was replying to you saying that "Were this to be done again h_addr_list's type would probably have been in_addr**", which couldn't work.

Comment: @BillyONeal, a union couldn't work because you can't tell all types of network addresses.

Comment: @Andrey: Why not? Adding union members (when new internet address types are supported) is a source and binary safe change.